# How to send Spark metrics to Graphite on Standalone cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, metrics, graphite

I try to send Spark metrics to Graphite using the following configuration:

```
*.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
*.sink.graphite.host=85.10.206.170
*.sink.graphite.port=2003
*.sink.graphite.period=1
*.sink.graphite.unit=minutes

# Enable jvm source for instance master, worker, driver and executor
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

application.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

saved on `/data/configurations/metrics.properties`.

I submit my application with these properties :

```
--files=/data/configuration/metrics.properties --conf spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties
```

I get the following error:

```
com.test.MyApp: metrics.properties (No such file or directory)
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: metrics.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsConfig$$anonfun$1.apply(MetricsConfig.scala:50) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsConfig$$anonfun$1.apply(MetricsConfig.scala:50) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsConfig.initialize(MetricsConfig.scala:50) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.<init>(MetricsSystem.scala:93) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$.createMetricsSystem(MetricsSystem.scala:222) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:361) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:188) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:842) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:80) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:133) ~[spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar:1.4.1]
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: try like file:////data/configuration/metrics.properties. also make sure the metrics.properties file exists in <Spark-Home>/conf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** `spark.metrics.conf` should be an absolute path.

NB: A star (`*`) refers *any* metric source available in Spark which can be `driver`, `executor`, external `shuffleService`, `master`, `applications`, `worker`, `mesos_cluster`.

TIP: You can access the metrics using corresponding URLs for the services, e.g. 4040 for the driver, 8080 for Spark Standalone’s master and applications, using `http://localhost:[port]/metrics/json/` URL.